# resize Image kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a ScatterLayout in kivy into which I add an Image object that contains a plot file from matplotlib, as in this sample

```
ScrollView:
    ScatterLayout:
        do_rotation: False
        scale_min: 0.5
        id: plot_content
        Image:
            source: file_path
            nocache: True
```

Sometimes the plots displayed are very wide:

http://s11.postimg.org/rad8zigqr/plt_wide.png

and I would like to fit them vertically, i.e., the plot having all the height available in the widget.

I have been able to create buttons with zoom in/out functionality by changing the scale property of Scatter, but I can't figure out a way to change the plot image height while keeping the image ratio.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: You say you want to change the height while keeping the image ratio, but this would only make the image wider while this doesn't seem to be what you wanted from your previous statements. Do you really want the image to be taller but not wider?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear in the post. Yes, I would like to make the image wider, while maintaining the ratio, up to the point where the height of the plot would match the height of the container widget. This would mean that the final image would be much wider, but at least the y-axis would be clearly visible. The image could then be panned to either side using the mouse touch.